# How to get Javascript stacktrace - JavscriptExecutor Selenium WebDriver

Tags: javascript, selenium

I'm using JavscriptExecutor to inject javascript into browser. The injected Javascript has custom error which I want to see in selenium when that error is thrown.

```
Javascript: 

var testError = function(){
    throw new Error("Javascript custom error!");
};

testError();
```

When I inject the above code, I'm exepecting "Javascript custom error!" error to be displayed in Selenium, but I'm getting below error,

```
org.openqa.selenium.WebDriverException: JavaScript error (WARNING: The server did not provide any stacktrace information)
Command duration or timeout: 160 milliseconds
Build info: version: '2.33.0', revision: '4ecaf82108b2a6cc6f006aae81961236eba93358', time: '2013-05-22 12:00:17'
System info: os.name: 'Windows 7', os.arch: 'x86', os.version: '6.1', java.version: '1.7.0_25'
Session ID: 9bff006b-9e50-418c-a3cf-49f1d16a6093
Driver info: org.openqa.selenium.ie.InternetExplorerDriver
```

When it says 'The server did not provide any stacktrace information', is there any reason for it? Is there anyway I can get the error to be displayed in Selenium? I want error to be displayed like,

```
org.openqa.selenium.WebDriverException: Javascript custom error!
```

Is this possible?

Comment: Whats the use case here? Why is this needed?

Comment: I'm automating an app where I have developed javascript file which will imported into browser during test execution. this file has several custom errors which will be thrown when certain conditions are not met. I'll be calling functions in that file using javascriptexecutor, so whenever error occurs I want that error to be displayed as is in Selenium.